# Centering an image on screen using CSS - Random Screen/Image dimensions

Tags: javascript, css, enyo

I have to create a web page that for the purposes of this question is a single image centered both vertically and horizontally in the center of the screen.  It has the following requirements:

- The screen size of the client is unknown (mobile)
- The image is user-defined and therefore is of unknown dimensions
- The image must be perfectly centered both vertically and horizontally on all devices
- The image centering must persist through a screen rotation (i.e. from portrait to landscape)

Being a bit of a CSS newb, I went and created this the only way I knew how, using javascript to position the content:
http://jsfiddle.net/error454/8YL9a/

I'm looking for a solution that functions identically to my solution but uses CSS instead of hard equations.

Comment: What's the benefit of using pure CSS instead of your javascript?

Comment: What I've shown is the tip of the iceberg for what I really have to create.  If I use javascript and a bunch of magic calculations, I will be the product owner for life.  I would prefer something that any web developer would be able to maintain in my absence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;

display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;
```

CSS3 property, bad support : webkit, mozilla. Only way to do it with clean markup and CSS without JS.

edit 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/t8qtn/6/

edit 2 : for future proofing, the prefixless version is

```
display:box;
box-orient:horizontal;
box-pack:center;
box-align:center;
```

Comment: Flexible Box Model here I come!

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice article on centering: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

It should be something like:

```
.vcenter { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
.hcenter { display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

And then apply both classes to your image:

```
<img class="vcenter hcenter" src="..."/>
```

Update: you could simply use a table like here http://www.sorinvasilescu.ro/

Comment: Updated: you could use tables, but they've been considered deprecated for layout purposes for ages...